# Animate.css - animation starts smoothly and bumps in towards the end

Tags: animate.css

I have a SPA where the content area fades in to the left when loaded using Animate.css.

This work fine for almost all pages except a few.
The animation on this few misbehaving pages start smooth but finish animation abruptly towards the end.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly what the root cause is, but the issue on the few pages was an animation on a nested element of the loaded page (again Animate.css).

For example when I load the page "container" and it has another element inside of it using a css animation, I will get the above mentioned issue.

```
<div id="container" class="animated fadeInLeft">
    .... 
     ...
      <div id="nested" class="animated flipInX">
```

When I remove the animation `class="animated flipInX"` from the nested element, the container fades in smoothly like all other pages.

**Workaround** for this issue:

- Attach the animation class via javascript code to the nested element(s):

  `$("#nested").addClass("animated flipInY");`

This worked in my case.